Graphviz vertical align subgraph with node while using left to right
I am trying to create a subgraph that is below the MEMOR node using Graphviz and I am struggling to get them lined up correctly,
This is what I have tried so far:

I want to get the ST boxes to be below MEMOR and reading to be the furthest to the right.
Digraph {
  layout = dot
  rankdir=LR;

ESCS[shape = box]

Gender[label = "Gender \n (female)", shape = box]


{ESCS, Gender} -> MEMOR


MEMOR -> {ST27Q01,ST27Q03, ST27Q05, ST27Q07}
subgraph cluster0 {
    style=invis;
    ST27Q01,ST27Q03, ST27Q05, ST27Q07[shape = box]
    ST27Q01 -> ST27Q03 -> ST27Q05 -> ST27Q07 [style = "invis"]
}

READING[shape = box, rank = "max"]
MEMOR -> READING

}

The end result being something like this


Did you search Stack Overflow? Did you see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75149813/graphviz-question-vertical-then-horizontal-alignment

That is a good approach that I haven't thought about that might suit my needs I'll play around with it.

Does this work (with some tweaking)?
Digraph {
  layout = dot
  rankdir=LR;
  splines=false  // added

ESCS[shape = box]

Gender[label = "Gender \n (female)", shape = box]


{ESCS, Gender} -> MEMOR

subgraph clusterA{
  peripheries=0
   {rank=same
   MEMOR
   tbl1 [shape=none label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1"><tr><td port="p1">ST27Q01</td><td port="p2">ST27Q03</td><td port="p3">ST27Q05</td><td port="p4">ST27Q0</td></tr></table>>]
    tbl1 -> MEMOR [style=invis]  // kludge to put memor above table
    edge [constraint=false]      // more of same kludge to put memor above table  
    MEMOR ->  tbl1:p1
    MEMOR ->  tbl1:p2
    MEMOR ->  tbl1:p3
    MEMOR ->  tbl1:p4
    }
}
subgraph clusterB{
  peripheries=0
   {rank=same
   ELAB
   tbl2 [shape=none label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1"><tr><td port="p1">ST27Q01</td><td port="p2">ST27Q03</td><td port="p3">ST27Q05</td><td port="p4">ST27Q0</td></tr></table>>]
    tbl2 -> ELAB [style=invis]  // kludge to put elab above table
    edge [constraint=false]      // more of same kludge to put elab above table  
    ELAB ->  tbl2:p1
    ELAB ->  tbl2:p2
    ELAB ->  tbl2:p3
    ELAB ->  tbl2:p4
    }
}

READING[shape = box, rank = "max"]
{ MEMOR ELAB } -> READING

}

Giving:


This works, i'll have to take some time to understand what it is doing. I haven't seen tables in nodes before.

they are documented here: https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html.  Not "real" HTML, just HTML-like.  But they work.
